# Contact and AccountContactRole relationship [SOQL]

Tags: soql, query, accountcontactrole

I am trying to create a list of all users associated with a certain account and their roles (from the `AccountContactRole` table) but i can't figure out how.

My current SOQL is:

```
Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone FROM Contact Where AccountId = '00120000001Q8PB' AND Id IN (Select ContactID from AccountContactRole WHERE  AccountId = '00120000001Q8PB')
```

But the problem is that this only gives me a list of users who are in the subquery (who have roles in the `AccountContactRole` table) not all users.

Edit #2: I need a list of all users (from the Contact table) with a left join of the Role field (from the AccountContactRole), not inner join. (as the latter will return results of Contact who only have Roles, the first should return all contact regardless if they have a Role or not)

Comment: Aren't you *trying* to filter on only those users? That seems to be the desired behavior?

Comment: No, the query filters only on those users, but i need all users and their contact roles (i just posted my query to show in which direction i was going, which is wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to retrieve all the AccountContactRole child records for the contacts, your query should be this:

```
List<Contact> contacts = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone, (Select Id FROM AccountContactRoles) FROM Contact Where AccountId = '00120000001Q8PB'];
```

Then you can access the roles list for each contact in this way:

```
List<AccountContactRoles roles = contacts[0].AccountContactRoles;
```

See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm) on querying child records.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for List of all Contacts with their ContactRole of particular account then you can query like this:

> Select Id, Name,(SELECT AccountId,ContactId,Id,IsPrimary,Role FROM
>   AccountContactRoles) from Account where Id IN(Select AccountID from
>   AccountContactRole)

It gives you list of all ContactRoles associate with your account.

Comment: I just tried this, it gives me the same results as my own query, just in a little different format, but the number of results is the same (34, should be 155)

Comment: the records that are not in the result,do they have a Contact Role Assigned?